# Recommended way to break out of a Watchdog Timer (WDT) supported main loop

Tags: esp32, micropython, watchdog, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

I need to include hardware WDTs on both ESP32 and rp Pico based systems running micropython.  I am using the Thonny IDE and with an 8s timeout on the Pico I can interrupt (Cntrl-C) the system and quickly delete the main from the board.  This then allows me to continue development of the code.  This approach works with an 8s timeout but if I was working with much shorter delays I am not so sure that it would.  My concern is getting stuck with a main.py I can't change?  Is there a better way anyone can recommend to handle this.

Harry
PS:  Relative beginner with Python.  The more I know, the more I know I don't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works for me: add time.sleep() for 5 seconds in the beginning of your code where you can kill script from Thonny using CTRL+C before WDT has been initiated. This way you dont need to delete file manually from board, you just stop it's execution before WDT

Comment: That sounds so simple it has got to be the way to go ;-)  I have my code split into a boot and a main so I guess I could use the same technique to stop the boot before the main even runs.  Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: if this help you with your question and answer it- please mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: I have tried this and sure enough if you connect the board to the computers USB port you can stop execution with Ctrl-C before the WDT call occurs.  That does not appear to be the end of the story in my case because what happens next is that I get a "back end shut down" message which means the IDE stops listening.  Using the Thonny Start/Stop button gets you control back but that equates to a reset and you are back where you started.  Bottom line I still need to delete the main to get out of this loop,  Either way adding this delay as per the suggestion is a good idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, for my own development i've used VSCode + Pymakr plugin and it worked for me well. I'll try on Thonny...

Comment: well, i use ESP32 dev kit v1 with Micropython 1.19.1 and Thonny 3.3.13 on Windows and it works perfectly. After CTRL+C neither board neither backend is not restarted. Maybe it's different for pico board

Comment: That's really interesting to know.  I'm going to do some more work on this and report back.